# draft.js mid-text placeholder

Tags: javascript, draftjs

I would like to have a mid-text placeholder in draft.js. I'm building a very lightweight code editor, and when the user inserts a function, say, `foo()`, I would like to show text representing the arguments inside of the parenthesis. However, if the user still continues to type, the placeholder text would be overwritten by the users' continued typing. The documentation doesn't really make it clear if this is even possible. Mutable text areas don't auto-replace with user text, but that was the closest I've come. Here's an example scenario of what I'm trying to do:

1. Empty box
2. User enters `foo`
3. User enters `(` -- box contains `foo(`
4. My code autocompletes this into `foo()` without moving the cursor position
5. The editor displays `foo(arg1)`
6. The user types `5` -- box now contains `foo(5)`
7. The box now displays `foo(5)`

How can I do this in draftjs?

Comment: draft can do your scenario, what's the question?

Comment: @JiangYD How does it handle it?

Comment: just detecting the input and do repacement

Comment: @JiangYD That will result in an intermediate step where the text from entry as well as the placeholder both exist.

Comment: that's true. because entry not controlled by draftjs react state, but entry triggers the state change. to prevent the intermediate step, `arg1` need be selected I think.

Comment: @JiangYD Which means this wouldn't behave like a placeholder.

Comment: depends on how you define placeholder. select then replace by input not a problem I think. maybe you need hint other than placeholder?

Comment: @JiangYD If the user would hit delete while the placeholder is selected, it would be removed. This wouldn't behave like a normal browser placeholder.